# price differs before log in and after log in

Tags: magento-1.9, price, catalog-price-rules, product-prices

Am using magento 1.9.2.3. The problem am facing is that when I login the price of the product in the catalog is displayed including the tax amount and when logged out the prices are displayed without including the tax amount. Is there anything I should change at backend?

Answer (score 0):

There might be any tax rule configured for `login user` and not for `guest`, if you want to apply same for `guest` then simply add `Customer Tax Class` to that tax rule.

You can do this under **Admin > Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules**

Let me know if you need any further detail.

Comment: The problem is that since the guest is not a customer, there is no tax class associated with them.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong on that. You can go into Customers > Customer Groups and modify the NOT LOGGED IN record. There is a drop down for choosing a Tax Class.

Comment: Does it solve your problem?